# Are branes topological defects? How else could they be physical?

Tags: spacetime, string-theory, spacetime-dimensions, branes, topological-defects

As far as I understand, the [branes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brane) of [brane cosmology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brane_cosmology) are lower-dimensional "sub-manifolds" of some space. It was hard to imagine for me how such structure could exist and be physical. But then I learned of [topological defects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_defect), which are essentially that. So my question is:

> **Question:** Are the branes of brane cosmology supposed to be topological defects of some sort? If not, how else could a "sub-manifold" be something physical?

I also posed a [related question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/777497/156405) which received little attention. Please note that I have only an undergraduate understanding of physics, but are fine with advanced mathematics.

Comment: point particle is a 0-brane. It may or may not be topological, depending on its theory.

Comment: @Kosm Does this apply to higher-dimensional branes as well? Are they considered as defects in some theories and as unexplained fundamental objects in others?

Comment: yes, they are just generalizations of point particles. For example D branes are objects on which open strings of string theory end, so they are not fundamental like strings. And in effective low-energy field theory, they can be described as topological solitons in principle.

Comment: solitons of one theory can be described as "fundamental" particles in the dual theory - see electric-magnetic duality, or S-duality. So, the same would in general apply to branes. Depending on the description, they could be fundamental or topological.